# Determining heat capacity of gasses

Tags: thermodynamics, gas-laws, heat, mole, kinetic-theory-of-gases

I need a little help on answering a question which popped into my head while I was reading about gas laws:

> Suppose that I have three canisters, each holding a different gas of
>   unknown identity [let's call them gasses A, B, and C] . I also happen
>   to have another tank of a different volume in which these gasses can
>   be mixed as I please, and a pump to remove the gasses from the mixing
>   tank afterwards. Each of these containers is fitted with a pressure
>   and temperature gauge. Furthermore, I have a heating apparatus which
>   can be used to heat or cool the gasses inside any of the containers. I
>   want to determine the molar heat capacity of each of the gasses.
>   Assuming that no energy is lost to heating of the containers, is it
>   possible to determine the molar heat capacities of gasses A, B, and C
>   using this setup? If so, how? If not, why not?

I presume that yes, it is possible to do so. I'm thinking that, for instance, gas A at room temperature could be pumped into the mixing chamber, then the amount of moles of gas A in the mixing tank could be calculated using the PV=nRT formula. Then, gas B could be heated up to a certain temperature and pumped into the tank. Based on the fact that we know the amount of moles of gas A in the tank and the change in temperature and pressure, we can calculate the amount of moles of gas B. Afterwards, the mixing tank can be purged and a different combination of gasses can be pumped in. Rinse and repeat. Afterwards,I would get a system of equations that looks something like the following:

AF=BG

BH=CJ

CN=AL

Where A, B, and C are the heat capacities of each of the gasses, and F,G,H,J,N, and L each equal the amount of moles of a particular gas multiplied by the observed change in temperature and are known. Solving for A, B, and C would yield the molar heat capacity of each gas.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: That is a very detailed and complex scenario that "popped into" your head. Does the heating device tell you how much heat it delivers?

Comment: @KarstenTheis No.

Comment: I think if you know the heat capacity of one gas, you could figure out the heat capacity of the others. However, I don't think your set of equations is able to get absolute values (i.e. if I find a solution and then multiply all heat capacities by 2, it would still be a solution to the equations).